# Securing plywood underlayment to timber sub-floor

Tags: subfloor, plywood, underlayment, backer-board

I am laying 12mm plywood on existing timber flooring (before laying Hardiebacker board & ceramic tiles). Apart from screwing the ply to the sub-floor, should I also use grab adhesive or thinset mortar?

The reasoning for thinset (I'm told) is that it helps to fill & support the plywood over any low spots in the old timber floor (18mm tongue and groove on 400mm c/c joists).

Comment: How rough and wavy is the subfloor? 12mm (1/2") plywood won't span more than a few inches without feeling spongy. If it was 18mm (3/4") you'd have a lot more stiffness.

Answer (score 1):

I would glue and screw down the plywood.  If you use hardy backer board I would use a dash patch or leveling compound on that before you set your tile.  A good alternative would be to do a mud job on top of the plywood that would take care of the leveling problem.  A mud job is tar paper stapled to the plywood with a layer of stainless steel mesh nailed to that and a mixture of Portland cement and sand set on top of that.  The cement is leveled and suitable for thin set application.  This should last a very long time.